# Consuming infinite monadic streams with Streamly

Tags: haskell, streaming, streamly

I've got a function which produces an infinite list of monadic actions (HTTP calls in my case), something like this:

```
getStream = foldMap makeHttpCall [1..]
  where
    makeHttpCall bookId = ...
```

I'd like to be able to use this function like this:

```
S.take 10 $ (asyncly getStream)
```

Two things I'm trying to achieve:

- I don't want to pass the `10` to the `getStream` function
- I want the 10 HTTP calls to be made at the same time

The code above makes more than 10 HTTP calls, and whatever comes back first is passed in the stream. I've explored other combinators like `wAsyncly` and `parallely` but the behaviour stays the same.

Is there a way to achieve this in [Streamly](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streamly-0.2.0)?

---

Code samples above use the following imports:

```
import Streamly
import qualified Streamly.Prelude as S
```

Comment: `foldMap makeHttpCall` won't produce a list of monadic actions, it'll produce one monolithic action.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as expected with streamly-0.4.0 onwards. That is, it will generate 10 concurrent requests at most.